# Remote control old intercom

Tags: wireless

My brother has a motor disability and lives in my parents house. He uses an wheelchair and operating the intercom is way too difficult for him.

I was thinking to mount an RF relay switch, but unfortunately I don't know which one is appropriate.

I've measured the voltage, and the door switch from the intercom has 12V AC.

Can you recommend me a RF relay which can work for the 12V AC switch? All of the low voltage RF relay that I found are for DC. Wifi relay switches are a good option. Sonoff has something but also just for DC.